# @Observable is being re-init every time view is modified in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, observable

I am surprised and don't really understand the behavior I am seeing with the new @Observable framework in iOS 17.

It seems that if the view containing the @State var, ie viewModel, is modified, then the init of that viewModel will also be called. This is not the behavior of the prior StateObject method of using a viewModel.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var offset = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            InnerView()
                .offset(x: offset ? 200 : 0)
                
            Button("Offset") {
                offset.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}


// iOS 17 Observable method:

struct InnerView: View {
    
    @State var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    init() {
        self._viewModel = State(wrappedValue: ViewModel())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

@Observable
class ViewModel {
    
    init() {
        print("ViewModel Init")
    }
}


// StateObject method:

struct InnerView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    init() {
        self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    init() {
        print("ViewModel Init")
    }
}
```

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Don’t initialize in the init. Do it in line. Custom units have never been a good practice with SwiftUI because SwiftUI can recreate the view as it pleases.

Comment: @loremipsum That does not change the end result, and really it should not be expected to do so. Parametrized viewModel inits are supported.

Comment: What you are doing is [explicitly](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state/init(wrappedvalue:)) discouraged… you can try the version with “initial value” but it isn’t ideal.

Answer (score 3):

This is curious! I've dug into it a bit, and I think I understand the reason for the discrepancy. But before that we need to understand each case a bit better.

In the `@Observable` method, note that the initializer is being called each time you tap on 'Offset' but *the result of the initializer isn't being used (after the first call)*.

Being called each time makes sense, really. Try putting `print("Inner View init")` in the `InnerView`'s initializers. You'll see that the init is being called each time the InnerView is rebuilt.

So on every rebuild, `State(wrappedValue: ViewModel())` is being called, and of course, that requires that `ViewModel()` be evaluated and passed into `State(...)` as `wrappedValue`.

But some magic is happening inside here, that's beyond my ability to see (but I can guess at implementations, so not that magical), because only the first instance of `wrappedValue` is used. I convinced myself of this by making each instance distinct (using a global and a instance counter) as follows:

```swift
var globalCounter = 0

// iOS 17 Observable method:

struct InnerView: View {
    @State private var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    init() {
        print("Inner View init")
        self._viewModel = State(wrappedValue: ViewModel())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Text("State counter is \(viewModel.counter)")
            Text("Global counter is \(globalCounter)")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


@Observable
private class ViewModel {
    var counter: Int
    
    init() {
        globalCounter += 1
        counter = globalCounter
        print("ViewModel Init")
    }
}
```

Since the "State counter is ..." label in our view doesn't update, while the global counter changes, we can conclude that only the first instance is being used.

However, this begs the question, *why does the initializer not get called each time for the other method?* Again, you can see (through adding `print("Inner View init")` as in the first method) that the InnerView initializer is being called each time. So it looks like the line `self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel())` is being called each time you click on the `Offset` button. But `ViewModel()` is not being called (as evidenced by lack of print from inside the ViewModel initializer). So how can this be?

I think it's because of the `@autoclosure` clause on this line in the SwiftUI header defining the initializer for `StateObject`:

`@inlinable public init(wrappedValue thunk: @autoclosure @escaping () -> ObjectType)`

So for `StateObject` the `wrappedValue` argument is [being converted to a closure](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/autoclosure/). And it's only being called when it's needed (ie on establishment of State for the View).

So, your question was, "Is this the expected behavior?" I think I have shown where the discrepancy comes from. Is it expected? I'd say there isn't much of an expectation at this level of detail. `Edit:` The more important expectation that is being met, though, is that State entities (whether classic State, Observed State, or StateObject) that relate to a particular view are being created only once and being retained for the lifetime of the view.

In the case of @Observed, there are some extra instances being created and discarded, and there's an efficiency hit from that. But your program behaviour will probably not be unaffected.

Having said that, my *preference* would be that Apple updated the `State` initializer to also use an `autoclosure` in the future. (Or at least give us an alternate initializer)

Also note that if the current discrepancy is a problem for you, you might be able to build a workaround, depending on your circumstances, and if my above inferences are correct.

I hope that helps!

Comment: That is an odd behavior and completely breaks expectation coming from the StateObject. It did have effect in my case as I had function calls on init that referenced other classes. 

It is interesting though that it does not affect its own data on consecutive inits.

Comment: Yes, I can see how that could happen. In case you aren’t familiar with this concept, that situation is identified as code that has [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), and is generally discouraged. It is preferred that initializing your ViewModel should not affect the state of data not encapsulated in that data structure. As I said, you might be able to build in workarounds, but I’d encourage you to try removing side-effects first.